# Pivoting 2 aggregate value on id value in SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

My data looks like this:

Employee_ID    Created_Date    Status    Time_in_Seconds 
1              2019-11-02       1         50
1              2019-11-02       2         10
1              2019-11-01       1         110
1              2019-11-01       2         80
2              2019-11-02       1         280
2              2019-11-02       2         95
2              2019-11-01       1         300
2              2019-11-01       2         130

I would like to sum Time_in_Seconds values across Status values for each driver for the last 7 days:

The results should look like this:
Employee_ID    Status1    Status2
1              160         90
2              580         225

I tried union all queries but that does not work. This has to be some kind of pivot but I am not sure how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the data frame

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([('1','2019-11-02','1',50),('1','2019-11-02','2',10),('1','2019-11-01','1',110),('1','2019-11-01','2',80),('2','2019-11-02','1',280),('2','2019-11-02','2',95),('2','2019-11-01','1',3000),('2','2019-11-01','2',130)],['Employee_ID','Created_Date','status','Time_in_Seconds']) 

df.groupBy('Employee_ID').pivot('status').agg({'Time_in_Seconds':'sum'}).show()
```

[image]

Comment: Other than having one value which doesn't match OPs (`('2','2019-11-01','1',3000)` should be `('2','2019-11-01','1',300)`) this looks good.